# Understanding why a/b doesn't work, but fromInteger a / fromInteger b does

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, this works:

```
ghci>5/2
2.5
```

Great. But if I assign 5 and 2 to variables..

```
Main> let a = 5
Main> let b = 2
Main> a/b
<interactive>:68:2:
    No instance for (Fractional Integer)
      arising from a use of `/'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Integer)
    In the expression: a / b
    In an equation for `it': it = a / b
Main>
```

I get errors up the wazoo. The only way I can get around it is by saying:

```
*Main> fromInteger a / fromInteger b
2.5
*Main>
```

What is going on with fromInteger? Why do I need it to make this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Prelude> :t 5 / 2            -- The type is inferred to be a fractional
5 / 2 :: Fractional a => a
Prelude> :t (/)              -- ...because the type of (/)
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
Prelude> let x = 5
Prelude> let y = 2
Prelude> :t x                -- In GHC there are addditional type defaulting rules
x :: Integer                 -- Instead of Num a => a, a lone integral is typed as `Integer`
Prelude> :t y
y :: Integer
Prelude> :i Fractional       -- Notice that 'Integer' is not an instance of 'Fractional'
class Num a => Fractional a where
  (/) :: a -> a -> a
  recip :: a -> a
  fromRational :: Rational -> a
    -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
instance Fractional Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
instance Fractional Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
```

In brief?  GHCi type-defaults your let-bound variables to `Integer`, which do not have `Fractional` instances (because `Integer`s aren't fractions).  In a Haskell program compiled via ghc the types would unify.

EDIT: I should add that I am trying to note how `let x = 4` could be inferred as Double were it in a larger context, and not on GHCi.  In response to Hammar's answer, it isn't just monomorphism, but also has to do with type defaulting.  `a` and `b` can monomorphicly be `Double`, as in a GHC-compiled function, but because the combination of the monomorphism restriction and the line-by-line type inference we can't get either `x :: Num a => a` or `x :: Double` - both of which would have suited your needs.

Answer (score 10):

It's the [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) at work. The types of `a` and `b` get defaulted to `Integer`, which obviously can't be used with `/` since it only works on `Fractional` types.

You can fix this by adding a type annotation when defining `a` and `b`:

```
> let a = 5 :: Double
> let b = 2 :: Double
> a / b
2.5
```

or you can use decimal literals which will default to `Double`:

```
> let a = 5.0
> let b = 2.0
> a / b
2.5
```

This would not be a problem if these three lines were type checked together, as they would be in a compiled module, or if you had entered

```
let a = 5; b = 2 in a / b
```

However, when typed separately in GHCi, they are type checked one at a time, so the defaulting that is applied when evaluating `let a = 5` picks `Integer` because at that point the only constraint on `a` is `Num`. It doesn't know about the `Fractional` constraint that we need in order to use `/` with it later.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, this is the fault of the [Monomorphism Restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction). Instead of annotating all your types like `(a :: Double) / (b :: Double)`, I find it easier to just turn it off:

```
Prelude> :set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
Prelude> let a = 5
Prelude> let b = 2
Prelude> a / b
2.5
```

(You can save the `:set` action in your [.ghci file](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/ghci-dot-files.html), so you don't need to write it each time)

Comment: Where did you find `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction` and where can I find more things like it, for my other problems?

Comment: @Imray: the GHC user guide is long and dense, but full of useful tools like this. Try http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/ghc-language-features.html . The Haskell wiki also has lots of great information, but it's more spread out.